# Keyboard Aware Scrollview's extraScroll reduces when key is pressed in Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-keypad, react-native-scrollview

When textInput is clicked, the keyboardAwareScrollView works fine and scrolls up with the extra scroll height provided. But scrolls down just below the textInput when a key is pressed in Android. Works just fine in iOS. I want the extraScrollHeight to persist until the keyboard disappears.

In simpler terms, textInput is clicked, the keyboard pops up with extra 50 scroll height as given. But as a key is pressed, that extra height scrolls down.

Also open to suggestions for an alternative to KeyboardAwareScrollView.

```
   <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      enableOnAndroid={true}
      extraScrollHeight={50}>
      <View style={styles.inner}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Header</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder="Username" style={styles.textInput} />
        <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 1" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 2" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 3" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 4" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 5" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 6" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 7" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 8" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 9" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 10" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 11" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 12" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Username 13" style={styles.textInput} />
          <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => null} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    
 

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  inner: {
    padding: 24,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 36,
    marginBottom: 48,
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 36,
  },
  btnContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginTop: 12,
  },
});
```

In androidManifest.xml, I have adjustPan.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Comment: did you find any way ?