# Add extra height between textInput and keyboard in react native

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I have multiple text inputs. When focused, they just pop over the keyboard(using keyboardAwareScrollView). However, I want to add around 50 height between the input and the keyboard. The entire screen is a scroll view. I tried using keyboardAwareScrollView but it's quite inconsistent on Android. Also, is it possible using keyboardAvoidingView?

CODE WITH KEYBOARD AVOIDING VIEW

```
  const Instruction = ({navigation}) => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
  const suggestions = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'kiwi'];
  const labelExtractor = tag => tag;

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{flex: 1}}
      behavior="height"
      keyboardVerticalOffset={60}>
      <ScrollView
        scrollEnabled
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          padding: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }}>
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 1" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 2" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 3" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 4" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 5" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 6" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 7" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 8" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 9" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 10" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 11" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 12" style={styles.textInput} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Username 13" style={styles.textInput} />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Test')} />
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  inner: {
    padding: 24,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 36,
    marginBottom: 48,
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 36,
  },
  btnContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginTop: 12,
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    borderBottomColor: '#262626',
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    padding: 8,
  },
});

export default Instruction;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same using the `keyboardVerticalOffset` prop of the `KeyboardAvoidingView` as follows.

```js
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  keyboardVerticalOffset = {50} // this could be dependent on something else
  style = {{ flex: 1 }}
  behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} >
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: It worked in an example project but in other projects, it's adding extra grey space above the keyboard instead of showing the screen. I tried going through the Native docs but it isnt explained well

Comment: Could you provide your full code so I can look over it?

Comment: I have added the code it's adding a blank space over the content

Comment: I've had similar issues. I have good experience with [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view). Remove your scrollview and your keyboard avoiding view and replace them with `<KeyboardAwareScrollView> ... </KeyboardAwareScrollView>` after you installed the new library via npm or yarn. Does this help? Is this a possibility for your setup?

Comment: I usually use keyboardAwareScrollView myself. However in the same code above(cli not expo), when I add extra height prop, it works in ios and glitches in android(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168267/keyboard-aware-scrollviews-extrascroll-reduces-when-key-is-pressed-in-android)

Comment: Alright. Keyboardavoiding is usually a pain in react native. I'm afraid that I don't know right away how to deal with this case then.

Comment: I just dont know why keyboardAwareScrollview's extra height doesnt work in android. Have tried everything. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you [seen this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11681)? There could be some workarounds that work

Comment: yes, I have. KeyboardVerticalOffset is the distance between the top of the user screen and the react-native view. It cannot be used to add extra height below a textInput.

KeyboardAwareScrollView is the best library related to keyboard I have used so far. It works as intended in ios. And also in Android when you have adjustPan in android.xml file and enableOnAndroid={true}. Only issue is when you use extraHeight or extraScrollHeight prop. When extra height 50 is added, it adds the exta height on focus but as soon as a key is pressed, that 50 height scrolls down.